# How can I target the odd and even divs using CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to apply different CSS to the odd and even divs but the current code I am using doesn't work. I just want it to target the first child, AKA the divs, and not the children of the divs.

```css
.work-layer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  color: white;
  height: 100%;
}

.work-container:nth-child(odd) {
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 100px;
}

.work-container:nth-child(even) {
  text-align: left;
  padding-right: 100px;
}

.name {
  font-size: 3em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.desc {
  font-size: 1.75em;
  width: 40%;
}

.url {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: white;
}

.work-layer {
  height: 300px;
}

.layer-textastic {
  background-color: rgba(0, 133, 255, 1);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,800" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="work">
  <div class="work-container textastic">
    <div class="work-layer layer-textastic">
      <h1 class="name">Textastic</h1>
      <p class="desc">I made this website as an homage to a great little text editor for iOS known as Textastic</p>
      <a href="#" class="url">jordanbaron.me/Updated-Textastic-Site</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: there's only one `.work-container` div and it's index is 1, therefore your "odd" selector is hitting it, your "even" selector hits nothing.  what are you trying to do instead?

Comment: In you code you have only one div of own type...then how you expect your code will work for odd or even child....

Comment: I plan on adding more divs when I do more projects.

Comment: You existing style looks fine to me for what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can’t you just change `.work-container:nth-child(even)` and `.work-container:nth-child(odd)` to `.work:nth-child(even)` and `.work:nth-child(odd)` respectively. If this is not what you want, post a picture using like MS paint of what you want it to look like.

Answer (score 1):

Your Code with even and odd just works fine, I guess you want the text in the p-Tag also on the right side, the problem here is the width of 40% you had on the class .desc. Just add a div around with width 100%, and add float right to the text within the div (only for odd .work-container).

Edit: Instead of using the code above (and in the Snippet) you can just add the following 3 lines of code, it has the same Effect:

```
.work-container:nth-child(odd) p{
  margin-right: auto;
 }
```

```css
.work-layer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  color: white;
  height: 100%;
}

.work-container:nth-child(odd) {
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 100px;
}

.work-container:nth-child(odd) .inner-desc{
  float: right;
}

.work-container:nth-child(even) {
  text-align: left;
  padding-right: 100px;
}

.name {
  font-size: 3em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.desc {
  font-size: 1.75em;
  width: 100%;
}

.inner-desc{
  width: 40%
}

.url {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: white;
}

.work-layer {
  height: 300px;
}

.layer-textastic {
  background-color: rgba(0, 133, 255, 1);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,800" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="work">
  <div class="work-container textastic">
    <div class="work-layer layer-textastic">
      <h1 class="name">Textastic</h1>
      <div class="desc">
        <p class="inner-desc">I made this website as an homage to a great little text editor for iOS known as Textastic</p>
      </div>
      <a href="#" class="url">jordanbaron.me/Updated-Textastic-Site</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```